# Passing raw html to the model and rendering it

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I would like to pass the html form to the model and after loading the page - I use (Html.Raw (model) to generate the form correctly, I would like this form to be created and then, using a JS script, send it to some controller). When it tries to do this, it causes a quick reload of the page. This is my code:

Helper class:

```
public class Content
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }

public Content(string name)
{
    Name = name;
    Data = $"<form id=\"formid\" method=\"post\" asp-action=\"Submit\" class=\"form-horizontal\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"name\" value=\"@Model.name\"/></form>";
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Send()
{
    var res = new Content("Test");

    return View(res);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Submit(string name)
{
    return View();
}
```

Send.cshtml

```
@model Content

@Html.Raw(Model.Data)

<script>
    window.onload = function () {
    document.forms["formid"].submit();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Don't do that. Rendering is the *view*'s job, not the model's. If you want to compose HTML parts, use partial views and components. Although in this case there's nothing dynamic about that *Razor template*. There's no reason that snippet can't be written in the view directly

Comment: I'll repeat this - what you have isn't HTML, it's a Razor template that would be rendered into HTML if it appeared in the view. Why not add it as-is in the view?